# Phonegap Ajax call returns Internal Server Error

Tags: android, jquery, web-services, cordova

I newbie in Phonegap Android App Development. I am trying to connect my App with remote MS SQL Server Database, I wrote an ASP.Net Web-service also to connect these two.
But when I call this Web-service via JQuery ajax() method it returns "Internal Server Error".

**Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function button_clicked(){
            var name = $.trim($("#txtName").val());
            var contact = $.trim($("#txtContactNumber").val());
            var type = $.trim($("#txtType").val());

             if(name.length > 0)
             {
                 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://my-domain.com/DocNote_WebService/DoctorMaster.asmx/insertDoctor",
                   data: "{doctorName: "+ name + ",contactNumber: "+ contact + ",doctorType: " + type +"}",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                   dataType: "json",
                   success : function(data) {            
                        alert('Record Saved Sucessfully.....!!!!');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('ERROR: '+thrownError);
                    }
                 });
             }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="page1">
        <header><h1>DocNote</h1></header>
        <div class="content" data-role="content">
            <h3>Enter Doctor Info</h3>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="txtName" id="txtName"  placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="txtContactNumber" id="txtContactNumber"  placeholder="Contact Number"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="txtType" id="txtType"  placeholder="Type"/>
                    <br/>
                    <button id="btnSubmit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" onclick="button_clicked()">Submit</button>
                    <button id="btnCancel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Cancel</button>
                </div>

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

My Web-service Method :

```
[WebMethod]
    public void insertDoctor(String doctorName, String contactNumber, int doctorType) {
        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into DOCTOR_MASTER (DOCTOR_NAME, DOCTOR_CONTACT_NUMBER,DOCTOR_TYPE) values (@name,@contact,@type)",connection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", doctorName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact",contactNumber);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", doctorType);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong .....
Thanks in Advance .........

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code on the server to see what's causing the error?  Without that, "internal server error" is no help at all.

Comment: try getting the posted data with request.form["keyword"] on the server side and post the data this way:
data: { name : name , contact : contact , type : type }

Comment: @Archer : I tested my Web Service using a [Testing Tool](https://wizdl.codeplex.com/), and it works fine.

Comment: I think that @Emre was partially correct then.  Pass the data as an object, rather than a string.  Emre - a web service will take data as parameters, not form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found Solution [Here](http://forums.asp.net/post/5545996.aspx).

```
data: "{ firstName: 'Aidy', lastName: 'F' }"
```

Then, I modified my Code and it Worked.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://my-domain.com/DocNote_WebService/DoctorMaster.asmx/insertDoctor",
      data: "{doctorName:'" + doctorName + "', contactNumber:'" + contactNumber + "', doctorType:'" + doctorType + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
      dataType: "json",
      success : function(response) {            
          alert('Record Saved Sucessfully.....!!!!');                       
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert('ERROR: '+thrownError);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as an object, not a string...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://my-domain.com/DocNote_WebService/DoctorMaster.asmx/insertDoctor",
    data: {
        "doctorName": name,
        "contactNumber": contact,
        "doctorType": type
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {            
        alert('Record Saved Sucessfully.....!!!!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('ERROR: '+thrownError);
    }
});
```